# Does the Bible allow second cousins to marry?

Tags: marriage, christian-living, leviticus

I know that according to the Bible we are not allowed to marry our first cousins. But what if I want to marry my cousin whose grandfather and my grandfather were brothers, so that my father and my cousin's father are first cousins—which would make us [second cousins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cousin#Second_cousins)? Is this allowed according to the Bible? Are there any prohibitions in the Bible on second cousins marrying?

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE! And thanks for asking a question. For a quick overview of what this site is about, please take the [Site Tour](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour). The relationship you are asking about is that of second cousins. I've edited your question to include that information.